MemoryStorage не работает FSM есть помогите?
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage = MemoryStorage())
NameError: name 'MemoryStorage' is not defined

Что мне делать

подключить нужный модуль, вероятно.

Импортируйте MemoryStorage:
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage

dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=MemoryStorage())

